# android app fill screen with small drawable multiplied one next to other

Tags: android, view, drawable, fill

I have small drawable and want to fill Android app screen with it multiplied many times vertically and horizontally without scaling as needed for current screen resulution.
I've searched internet and looked properties of ImageView, SurfaceView, property `fill` scales image, not multiplies it, `Matrix` also doing other trick.

As I see now the solution is to make as big in resolution as needed one picture in graphic editor.

There is no way to tell Android to fill view by drawing one picture many times one next to other. Please confirm as loading my app with huge pictures seems unreasonable to me now.

Comment: see [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Bitmap) ^F XML Bitmap

Comment: @pskink thank you. I've read http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Bitmap
and it solves my issue. almost. is there way to center source so that clipped images were not only right and below, but also left and above - bitmap be symmetric? I doubted existence to my initial answer and doubt again, but hope Android can be beautifully symmetric.

Comment: never used that,  but maybe try `android:gravity`